# Build Gradle Android studio Build Slow

Tags: android, performance, gradle, build

I use Android Studio to build my android application. But my laptop take 5 mins to build app. I don't know why. It's always load to build gradle too slow. Here is my code Build Gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "thsoft.com.sosme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.5.0-rc-1'
}
```

Could you help me to solved it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enable offline mode to ignore up-to-date checks:

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

Or change build type to Debug :
Build Variants - > Debug ( Bottom Left corner AS)

Gluck!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the **gradle code**, but way **too many dependencies.** It depends on your **processor's speed and memory**. Try getting **8gb of memory** and you'll be just fine. According to official site, **minimum requirement is 4gb**!!

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Android Studio 2.0 preview release. Its just awesome and it will reduce the gradle build time for sure. Let's try

Comment: my version is 1.5. I don't find out ver 2.0 on help/check update

Comment: yes because it is just for developers preview. YOu can download it from here. http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

Answer (score 0):

to increase your build time you just need to increase your RAM 
and in your gradle file remove those dependencies  which are not required.

You have used play services which is huge. If you are using Google Cloud Messaging use com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0. definitely it will reduce your build time. Don't put whole play services. Be specific which play service you are using.

this Link may help you https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Good Luck

Comment: is operating system is also effect the performance issue of android studio

Comment: no ,operating system doesn't matter but RAM and predecessor really matter

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn might be this discussion help you, check the url https://plus.google.com/+RicardoAmaral/posts/e9PG6vSN5w3

Comment: but i think mac and linux operating system can built the gladle more fast as compare to Windows

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn if you have use google map v2 then you can use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0